# SIM808, not receive the complete json string from openweathermap

Tags: json, arduino, at-command, openweathermap, sim800

I'm trying to receive a Json string from OpenWeathermap with a SIM808 module and an Arduino.
A connection is established, but the "AT + HTTPREAD" command only outputs the first characters of the Json string.

It would also be interesting to learn how to save variables from the string.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

greetings from Germany

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial GSM808(7,8);

void setup()
{
 GSM808.begin(9600);  
 Serial.begin(9600);  
 delay(500);
}

void loop()
{
  
 GSM808.println("AT");                                                                                                                         
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
  
 GSM808.println("AT+COPS?");                                                                                                                        
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();

 GSM808.println("AT+CREG?");                                                                                                                       
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+CGATT=1");                                                                                                                       
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");                                                                                                 
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"internet.eplus.de\"");                                                                                                    
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();

 GSM808.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");                                                                                                                     
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPINIT");                                                                                                            
 delay(1000); 
 printSerialData();

 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");                                                                                                                                        
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
  
 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Rottenburg&appid=6f00d939cc59a518b4ce01f1ec08b3a9\"");                                     
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();  

 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPSSL=0");                                                                                                                
 delay(1000);                                                           
 printSerialData();

 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPPARA=CONTENT,application/json");                                                                                                                  
 delay(1000);                                                           
 printSerialData();

// GSM808.println("AT+HTTPDATA= 600,10000");     
// delay(2000);                                                           
// printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");     
 delay(1000);                                                           
 printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPREAD");                                                                                                       
 delay(3000); 
 printSerialData();
 
 GSM808.println("AT+HTTPTERM");  
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();

 GSM808.println("AT+SAPBR=0,1");                                                                                                         
 delay(1000);
 printSerialData();
 
}


void printSerialData()
{
 while(GSM808.available()!=0)
 Serial.write(GSM808.read());
 delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a problem with processing the entire response.

Your algorithm right now is basically:

1. Send the AT command
2. Wait long enough that you trust it's all finished putting data in the buffer
3. Take everything in the serial port buffer and print it out
4. Sleep and move on

But what if the response is too long for the buffer or the device doesn't want to put it in the buffer all at once? Then you're only going to get the initial part of the response and that is the behavior you are describing.

When processing the responses from AT commands it's better to start processing immediately and wait for the command response to finish or timeout rather than waiting a fixed time for the response. This will improve your efficiency too.

Consider changing your printSerialData() method to check for delimiters and keep going until you either get a delimiter (like OK or +ERROR) or until a timeout you specify in a parameter is reached. Your current while loop there will complete the second there is nothing in the buffer regardless of whether the command response is finished or not.